# Optimize code with ArrayList or TreeSet?

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures, arraylist, treeset

```
TreeMap<String,ArrayList<String>> statesToPresidents = new TreeMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    TreeMap<String,String> reversedMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    TreeSet<String> presidentsWithoutStates = new TreeSet<String>();
    TreeSet<String>statesWithoutPresidents = new TreeSet<String>(); while (infile2.ready())
    {
        String president = infile2.readLine();
        if (reversedMap.containsKey(president)==false)
            presidentsWithoutStates.add(president);
    }

    infile2.close();

    System.out.println( "\nThese presidents were born before the states were formed:\n");  // DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY

    // YOUR CODE HERE TO PRINT THE NAME(S) Of ANY PRESIDENT(s)
    //  WHO WERE BORN BEFORE THE STATES WERE FORMED = 10%

    Iterator<String> iterator = presidentsWithoutStates.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```

I was wondering if my program would run faster if I used an ArrayList instead of a TreeSet. I add the string president to the presidentWithoutStates TreeSet if it's not a key in reversedMap and when I print it out I need it sorted order. Should I use the TreeSet and sort as I go or should I just use an arraylist instead and sort at the end. I saw a similar question about this but that person wasn't continually adding elements like I am.

Edit: There are no duplicates

Comment: It seems to me like you are justifying the added overhead of of a TreeSet by using its advantages of both sorting and key lookup. If you were only using sort, you might as well just use an ArrayList, and if you were only using key lookups you should use a HashMap. Just my opinion though, there may be others that know more that disagree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break the running time down:

**ArrayList:**

- `n` inserts taking amortized `O(1)` each, giving us `O(n)`
- Sort takes `O(n log n)`, assuming you use the built-in `Collections.sort`, or an `O(n log n)` sorting algorithm.
- Iterating through it takes `O(n)`

Total = `O(n + n log n)` = `O(n log n)`

**TreeSet:**

- `n` inserts taking `O(log n)` each, giving us `O(n log n)`.
- Iterating through it takes `O(n)`

Total = `O(n log n + n)` = `O(n log n)`

**Conclusion:**

Asymptotically, we have the same performance.

In practice, `ArrayList` would probably be slightly faster.

Why do I say this? Well, let's assume it isn't. Then we could use `TreeSet` to sort an array faster than the method made specifically to sort it (the saving gotten from not having to insert into the `ArrayList` is fairly small). That seems counter-intuitive, doesn't it? If this were (consistently) true, Java developers would simply replace that method with `TreeSet`, wouldn't they?

One could analyse the constant factors involved with the sort versus the `TreeSet`, but that would probably be fairly complex, and the conditions under which the program is run also affects the constant factors, so it can't be exact.

**Note on duplication:**

The above assumes there isn't any duplicates.

If there were duplicates, you definitely shouldn't be doing a `contains` check if you were to use an `ArrayList`, but rather do the duplication removal afterwards (which can be done by simply ignoring consecutive elements which are the same during iteration after the sort). The reason the `contains` check should be avoided is because it takes `O(n)`, which could make the whole thing take `O(n²)` instead.

If there are many duplicates, `TreeSet` is likely to be faster, as it only takes `O(n log m)`, where `m` are the number of duplicates. The sorting option doesn't deal with duplicates so directly, so, unless `m` is really small, or you get lucky, still ends up taking `O(n log n)`.

The exact point where `TreeSet` becomes faster than the sorting option is really something to benchmark.

Comment: Are you taking into account the checking for duplicates prior to insertion? To me it would seem that insertion for ArrayList would be O(n^2)

Comment: @dcharms If you insert duplicates and just ignore them when iterating afterwards, you'd still end up with a O(n log n) algorithm. Added a note on that.

Comment: That makes sense and I hadn't thought about it that way. Thanks for the added note.